# Why do my Picture SRCSets + Sizes not work with my BS4 breakpoints?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm getting slowly mad trying to get this to work.

I have read a couple of articles on the use of picture srcset and I understand the part of using the picture tag for either art direction, or in my case another format (webp).

What I don't understand is why the relationship between srcset and sizes is not working like it should (IMO).

I'm trying to mimic the breakpoints of Bootstrap 4 (min-width 576px, 768px, 992px, 1200px) together with a row of columns - and added a couple of extra breakpoints at lower browser widths.

So what I came up with is this for the sizes tag:

```
(min-width: 300px) 230px, // if browser is minimum 300px, the slot that the image needs to fill is 230px
(min-width: 325px) 265px, // if browser is minimum 300px, the slot that the image needs to fill is 265px
(min-width: 450px) 375px, // ...
(min-width: 576px) 540px, 
(min-width: 768px) 624px, 
(min-width: 992px) 384px, 
(min-width: 1200px) 189px, 
150px // if browser width is lower than 300px, the slot that the image needs to fill is 150px
```

To make this easier to check, I created a srcset with exactly the sizes of the slots:

```
https://via.placeholder.com/230x150/ 230w, 
https://via.placeholder.com/265x150/ 265w, 
https://via.placeholder.com/375x150/ 375w, 
https://via.placeholder.com/384x150/ 384w, 
https://via.placeholder.com/540x250/ 540w,
https://via.placeholder.com/624x250/ 624w,
https://via.placeholder.com/189x100/ 189w,
https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/ 150w,
https://via.placeholder.com/600x350/ 600w
```

Why is my combination not working?

- Up until 300px browser width, the image used is 230px = correct
- Up until 450px browser width, the image used is 375px = correct
- Up until 576px browser width, the image that should be used is 540px, but 375px is still being used = not correct
- next up 375px is used up until 992px, while it should be 384px
- When browser width reaches 1200px, it should swap to the 189px, but it stays 375px

So, what I'm missing, or why doesn't this work?

An example has been created below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
      <picture>
          <source type="image/png"
                  srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/230x150/ 230w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/265x150/ 265w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/375x150/ 375w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/384x150/ 384w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/540x150/ 540w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/624x150/ 624w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/189x150/ 189w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/ 150w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/ 600w" 
                  sizes="(min-width: 300px) 230px, 
                  (min-width: 325px) 265px, 
                  (min-width: 450px) 375px, 
                  (min-width: 576px) 540px, 
                  (min-width: 768px) 624px, 
                  (min-width: 992px) 384px, 
                  (min-width: 1200px) 189px, 
                  150px" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x150/" class="img-fluid w-100">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because SRCSET doesn't work like CSS media queries. It will find the first condition it meets, and use that. I would change up your queries to use `max-width` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
      <picture>
          <source type="image/png"
                  srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/230x150/ 230w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/265x150/ 265w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/375x150/ 375w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/384x150/ 384w, 
                  https://via.placeholder.com/540x150/ 540w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/624x150/ 624w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/189x150/ 189w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/150x150/ 150w,
                  https://via.placeholder.com/600x150/ 600w" 
                  sizes="(max-width: 324px) 230px, 
                  (max-width: 449px) 265px, 
                  (max-width: 575px) 375px, 
                  (max-width: 767px) 540px, 
                  (max-width: 991px) 624px, 
                  (max-width: 1199px) 384px, 
                  (min-width: 1200px) 189px, 
                  150px" />
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/321x150/" class="img-fluid w-100">
      </picture>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-3 p-md-5 p-sm-0">    
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok,  this yields better results already, but why is the slot width 375px up until 320px browser width? It should be 230px ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...in your example from 300px to 325px screen width, you will get 230px image size. So, I just changed it to max-width: 324px.

Comment: I'll need to test it more tomorrow, but if you use the example above and resize your browser window to 320px .. do you get the 230px image size that becomes visible? If I try, I get the 375px image.

Comment: Yes, I get the 230px image up to 324px browser width, then it switches to 265px image, then to 375px image.

Comment: That's very weird. I'll need to test this tomorrow. I'll get back and accept your answer if I can reproduce, but on my laptop I cannot gain the same results. Is my Surface laptop reporting other dimensions than reality?

Comment: It may if your DPR is set to higher than 1. https://gyazo.com/08ab6bfb6aa9d78ed99d5a03aca8b6a9

Comment: Ok my DPR was set to 2.0 (didn't see the setting in the inspector). So stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Not stupid! It's really easy to miss when you're doing testing. Same with browser zoom. Accidentally set my browser zoom to 110% and couldn't figure out why things were off. It happens.